# LaTex обтекание текста

Tags: latex, tex

```
           \begin{figure}[p]
           \includegraphics{picture.png} 
           \caption{картинка}
           \label{ris:image}
           \end{figure}
```

Он ставит картинку в центр слайда, а весь текст перебрасывает вниз. как сделать так чтобы текст был слева, а картинка справа.

Также интересует как можно вставить код?

Comment: (1) Вам не нужно использовать плавающие иллюстрации, используйте подходящий пакет ([например, `wrapfig`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Wrapping_text_around_figures)). (2) [Книга Львовского](http://www.mccme.ru/free-books/llang/newllang.pdf) очень хороша. (3) Офтопик же!

Comment: А для кода `\usepackage{listings}`.

Comment: (Уже не уверен, что офтопик.)

Comment: @VladD точно уже не оффтопик. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4647/181472 ))

Answer (score 5):

Нужно подобрать нужные значения (вместо `0.4\textwidth` и `width=0.6\textwidth`) под вашу картинку и текст, обтекающий её.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{picture.png}
\caption{картинка}
\label{ris:image}
\end{wrapfigure}Он ставит картинку в центр слайда, а весь текст перебрасывает вниз. как сделать так чтобы текст был слева, а картинка справа. Также интересует как можно вставить код?
\begin{verbatim}
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
std::cout << "picture.png" << std::endl;
return 0;
}
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```